# Is there anything like Apple's Shark on Linux?

Tags: linux, shark

I'm looking for alternatives to Apple's [Shark](http://developer.apple.com/tools/sharkoptimize.html) on Linux. I'm looking for a statistical profiler - not gprof. I know about oprofile, but would like something a bit more polished. Appreciate any suggestions with advantages/disadvantages relative to Shark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing to Shark on Linux is [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com). It's a sampling profiler that collects callstacks and is system-wide. It has a GUI that lets you see functions, source, and assembly.

Comment: Zoom is actually written by some of the original Shark developers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Sysprof: http://www.daimi.au.dk/~sandmann/sysprof/

It's much simpler to use than oprofile, but probably not as fully-featured as Shark.